# Shrapoint 2013 does not have border underneath Library name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SP 2010 when I had a library in a page the library name displayed a nice soft blue line/border underneath the library name..

When I have the same library in SP 2103 only the Library name displays.

Any suggestions..note for SP2010 its all oob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI for 2013 was changed in many places.

You can add your own CSS style *overruling SharePoints style definition*

```
<style>
 .pageTitle{
   border-bottom:blue;
 }
</style>
```

Several places you can add your own stylesheet

- Site Settings -> Masterpage (*if Publishing Features are enabled*)
- Editting the MasterPage with SP Designer *add a link to your own stylesheet*
- Site- Settings > Design Manager *Create a whole new Design*
- Inside a CEWP *but that will only get you the styles on the one page*
- Using a Browser Plugin (Chrome) Stylish *this changes anything in the page you want, but only in your browser*